MacBook Pro 5,4 (Mid 2009) crashes every time I try to update the display drivers on Windows 10?
I have a MacBook Pro 5,4 (Mid 2009) running Windows 10 via Boot Camp 4.0.4
I updated the drivers but after rebooting I got a boot loop, so I booted into safe mode and deleted the display driver.
It worked fine but then when I try to install the driver's from Nvidia's website it just crashes mid-setup and after reboot it goes back to Microsoft basic display adapter.
Everything else works fine. Any ideas on how to fix this?

@DavidPostill This is not "hackintosh" (macOS running is hardware not licensed for, i.e., non-Apple). This is Windows 10 running on Apple hardware via Boot Camp.

My apologies, but your question was confusing, as you said running "in Windows 10". I have clarified it for you and reopened. Please review my [edit]. Thanks.
